# Parenthesis in When conditions with slim pdo

Tags: php, sql, slim, slim-pdo

Using PHP Slim PDO how could one express :

(condition 1 OR condition 2) AND (condition 3 OR condition 4)

That would be something like that (but *obviously this code does not work*) :

```
$pdo->select()->from('items')
  ->whereOpenParenthesis()
  ->where('color', 'red','OR')
  ->where('size', 'xl')
  ->whereCloseParenthesis()
  ->whereOpenParenthesis()
  ->where('stock', '10','OR')
  ->where('price', '99')
  ->whereCloseParenthesis();
```

***without raw SQL***

(these are random data for the sack of the question)

Comment: `$pdo->select()->from('items')
  ->where('color', 'red','OR')
  ->where('size', 'xl' 'OR')
  ->where('stock', '10');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added these methods in those classes.
Obviously, that would be better for you to extend the SLIM PDO itself, instead of adding some code.

vendor\slim\pdo\src\PDO\Clause\WhereClause.php

```
public function openParenthesis(){
     $this->container[] = ' ( ';
}
public function closeParenthesis(){
    $this->container[] = ' ) ';
}

//Function amended :

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    if (empty($this->container)) {
        return '';
    }

    $args = array();

    foreach ($this->container as $where) {
        $args[] = $where;
    }

    $str = implode('', $args);
    $str = str_replace('(  AND', ' AND ( ', $str);
    $str = str_replace('(  OR', ' OR ( ', $str);

    $str = ' WHERE '.ltrim($str, ' AND');

    return $str;
}
```

vendor\slim\pdo\src\PDO\Statement\StatementContainer.php

```
public function openParenthesis() {
     $this->whereClause->openParenthesis();
}

public function closeParenthesis() {
    $this->whereClause->closeParenthesis();
}
```